# Showing that $3n<n!$ whenever $n$ is an integer with $n \geq 7$

Tags: inequality, proof-writing, induction, factorial

> How can we show that:
>   $$3n< n!$$
>   whenever $n$ is an integer such that $n \geq 7$ ?

I was thinking that we can prove this by showing that such case is true with any integer above 7, but then I remembered that I think that only works when we are disproving something.  Is there any way to show this another way?  Thanks!

Edit: I was thinking along the lines of using base case of 7 and plugging in examples to proof?

Comment: It is true $\forall n\geq 4.$

Comment: Just 3n, sorry for the confusion

Comment: Similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72831/how-to-prove-n-n-if-n-2-by-induction

Answer (score 11):

Hint: $(n-1)!>3,\forall n\ge4$
Multiplying with n on both sides we get $n!>3n,\forall n>3$.

Comment: Not really sure where to go from here..

Comment: Very efficient!

Comment: @mario1433 : Thats it, you are finished after this

Comment: Now I think its clear @mario1433

Comment: Is there a "less efficient" way of proving it such that we don't use ∀?

Comment: @mario1433 $\forall n>3$ means that it is valid for all n greater than 3.

Comment: Abraha - yeah, but can we do this using base case, RHS, LHS, for example?

Comment: @mario1433 $\forall \ n \geq 7 \subset \forall \ n>3$

Comment: is this inductive?

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a less efficient way to approach this proof, try proof by induction, if for no other reason than practice with inductive proofs:

Let $P(n)$ be the assertion: $$3n<n!,\;\;n\geq 7\tag{P(n)}$$

- Establish the assertion is true for the **base case** $n = 7$, by computing $$3\cdot 7 < 7! \tag{P(7)}$$ and confirming the inequality holds for $n = 7$.
- Assert the inductive hypothesis: assume the assertion $P(n)$ is true for $n = k$: that is, assume $$3k < k!\tag{inductive hypothesis: $P(k)$}$$
- Then make the inductive step by showing that, using the inductive hypothesis, it follows that $$3(k+1) < (k + 1)!\tag{P(k+1)}$$

If you can prove $P(k + 1)$ follows from $P(k)$, then together with the truth of the base case, you conclude: therefore $P(n)$ is true.

The task is noting that $$3(k+1)=\color{blue}{\bf 3k}+3<\color{blue}{\bf k!}+3<k!(k+1) = (k + 1)!$$ (note we used the inductive hypothesis $\color{blue}{\bf 3k<k!}$). Hence $P(k+1)$ is indeed true, given $P(k)$.

With the base case, you are done, you have proven that $P(n)$ is true for $n\geq 7$.

Comment: So would this mean we start with Base Case:  stating LHS < RHS by plugging in 7.  Then where would we go from here?  Thanks!

Comment: the OP was talking about a base case so I believe this is what he was talking about

Comment: Wait no..it has to be n >= 7 not n <= 7!

Comment: This is really nice.  Except how do I show the inductive step is proven with case k+1?  As in. how can we prove P(K+1) follows from P(k)?  Thanks!

Comment: Let me know how far you get: to work is showing that $3(k+1) = 3k + 3 \lt k! + 3 \leq (k + 1)!$ (note we used the inductive hypothesis $3k < k!$)

Comment: Yes, I figured that but what else is needed to show this after that inequality?  Thanks!  (Sorry, this was my only problem in the proof!  Should have mentioned that haha)

Comment: If you can show what I wrote in my comment, then you have shown that $3(k+1) \lt (k+1)!$...and that's exactly what you need: you've established the truth of $P(k+1)$ given $P(k)$. With your $P(7)$, you are done!!

Comment: Does this help now? I edited my post...but also read my reply above.

Answer (score 1):

Use induction to prove this

Take your hypothesis as $P(n) : 3n < n!$

First show that $P(7)$ is true

Next assume $P(n)$ is true and show that $P(n+1)$ is true.

If you are still confused why this is a valid proof I can explain, just comment and let me know

$$
P(n+1) : 3(n+1) < (n+1)! \\
3n + 3 < n!(n+1)
$$
By the inductive hyposthesis we know
$$
3n < n!
$$

So plug and chug and look at what your inequality gets you...

(This is exactly what @amWhy has, I just tried to be more precise I guess... anyways she's completely right I'm just trying to clear up your question on her answer)

Comment: Well isn;t his missing the validation of induction step?

Comment: How do we show P(n+1) is true?

Comment: I left that for you to do :P but I'll put in some hints...